# Javascript change text onClick and then change back again

Tags: javascript, text, onclick, hyperlink

I am trying to change the text of a link on click and then change back again to the original when clicked again. I am able to change the text, (from READ MORE... to CLOSE) but have been fighting to change the text back again (from CLOSE to READ MORE...)

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function changeText(idElement){
 if(idElement==1){
 document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML ='Close';
 } else if(idElement==2){
 document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML ='Close';
 }
 }
 </script>

 <a id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(1)">Read More...</a>
 <a id="element2" onClick="javascript:changeText(2)">Read More...</a>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You should spruce up on the concept of "unobtrusive javascript", mate...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
function changeText(idElement) {
    var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
    if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
        if (element.innerHTML === 'Read More...') element.innerHTML = 'Close';
        else {
            element.innerHTML = 'Read More...';
        }
    }
}
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/

Answer (score 7):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(this.innerHTML =='Read More'){this.innerHTML = 'Close'}else{this.innerHTML = 'Read More'}">Read More</a>
```

Just change the `javascript:void(0);` with the open/close function and make sure to return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeText(idElement){
    if(idElement==1){
        document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML ='<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
    } else if(idElement==2){
        document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML ='<a href="http://woork.blogspot.com">Woork</a>';
    }
}
</script>

<ul>
<li id="element1">Google</li>
<li id="element2">Woork</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeText(1)">Change Google into a link</a><br/>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeText(2)">Change Woork into a link</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function only calls one value, and once called, the elements in question aren't changing their function calls.

To clarify, I believe you should use a method of toggling the text instead of changing it. Please refer to the toggling portions of [this tutorial](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/) to have your links change text as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your function is only setting the value to be 'Close' when the element gets a click. you need to check what the value is before you set it. so you should modify your function to be like this:

```
    function changeText(idElement){
        if(idElement==1){
            if( document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML == 'Read More' ){
                document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML = 'Close';
            } 
            else if( document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML == 'Close' ) {
                document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML = 'Read More';
            }
        } 
        else if(idElement==2){
            if( document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML == 'Read More' ) {
                document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML = 'Close';
            }
            else if( document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML == 'Close' ) {
                document.getElementById('element'+idElement).innerHTML = 'Read More';
            }
        }
    }
```

}